# xcode: can not open simulator: Error saving com.apple.lsdidentifiers.plist : (null)

Tags: xcode, simulator

This is the log in console.
2016-10-19 4:35:30.377 PM com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService[761]: Error saving /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/14ABD200-69D3-441D-8FAA-731F5F00F678/data/tmp/com.apple.lsdidentifiers.plist : (null)

/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/14ABD200-69D3-441D-8FAA-731F5F00F678/data/tmp/ is an empty folder.

Meanwhile, my xcode can not load xib or storyboard properly.  "Internal error occurred, Editing functionality maybe limited"

I did clear /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ folder, doesnt help, re-install xcode doesnt work.

environment: OS: EI 10.11.6, xcode: 8.0  simulator:Version 10.0 (SimulatorApp-700.5.3

Comment: Can you file a radar? Please run sysdiagnose and attach its output. Also attach logs from ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator. The error you are seeing should be a non-fatal error and is probably a red-herring but we would love to look into this for you.

Comment: Please check my reply, I fixed it by disable SIP, I have no idea why this could be the reason, and I dont remember I changed SIP settings. But actually it works.

Comment: Unfortunately if everyone just disables SIP then we can't figure out why it is happening and fix the underlying problem. If anyone out there wants to help please provide the logs and sysdiagnose. You can send me the radar number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by turn off System Integrity Protection in El Capitan.
I totally have no idea when I updated mac os, and got this issue. 
Until I noticed that I cant start mysql, which has similar issue 'Could not create unix socket lock file /tmp/mysql.sock.lock'

Then I thought something went wrong with my os settings.

steps:
Restart your Mac.
Before OS X starts up, hold down Command-R and keep it held down until you see an Apple icon and a progress bar. Release. This boots you into Recovery.
From the Utilities menu, select Terminal.
At the prompt type exactly the following and then press Return: csrutil disable
Terminal should display a message that SIP was disabled.
From the  menu, select Restart

for more information https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really

Comment: Based on that, it sounds like disabling SIP is just working around the real underlying problem.  I suspect you have somehow messed up the permissions on /tmp (/private/tmp), possibly like the user in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238266/xcode-8-simulator-crashing/40266748#40266748

Answer (score 0):

The error message is benign and can be ignored.  Sorry about the noise in syslog.  The issue has since been resolved in the Xcode 8.1 betas.

If you deleted ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices while CoreSimulatorService was running, the service will be in an inconsistent state.  You should SIGKILL it to cause it to relaunch in a new state.

Your 'Internal error occurred, Editing functionality maybe limited' error message is likely unrelated to either of those things.  Most users see that because they're trying to use multiple copies of Xcode.app at the same time.  It's perfectly fine to have multiple Xcodes installed, but you can only use one at a time.  If that's not the issue you're seeing, you will need to provide more information about the error.

Comment: I did install xcode 8.1 beta in another folder , still get same error. the simulator come with 8.1 got same error.

Comment: Please check my reply, I fixed it by disable SIP,  I have no idea why this could be the reason, and I dont remember I changed SIP settings. But actually it works.

Comment: Based on your mysql error as well, I suspect that disabling SIP is just working around the real issue.  If you can please re-enable SIP, reproduce, and then take a sysdiagnose (sudo sysdiagnose -q), I'll help you triage the problem.  File a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com, including the sysdiagnose as well as the output of `stat /tmp` and `stat /private/tmp`