# launchd_sim crashing: could not create temporary state directory

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

> The issue is fixed with recent update of Mac OSX.

I am using Xcode 8 on Mac Mini running OSX El Capitan (10.11.6). When I deploy my app on simultor is shows following error messages:

1. **"launchd_sim quit unexpectedly"**
2. **"Unable to boot the iOS simulator"**

How to resolve such type of issues?

Detailed exception report:

```
Process:          launchd_sim [16545]

Path:             /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/sbin/launchd_sim

Identifier:       launchd_sim

Version:          4.0.0 (972.1.5)

Code Type:        X86-64 (Native)

Parent Process:   ??? [1]

Responsible:      launchd_sim [16545]

User ID:         501



Date/Time:        2016-10-25 13:53:29.247 +0530

OS Version:       Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1004)

Report Version:   11

Anonymous UUID:  6844F1F8-F647-09F6-8FB0-A7B9C14F843B



Time Awake Since Boot: 17000 seconds



System Integrity Protection: enabled



Crashed Thread:   0

Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread



Exception Type:   EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)

Exception Codes:  0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Exception Note:   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY



Application Specific Information: could not create temporary state directory
```

**EDIT:**

**To check disk permissions:**

```
sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --verify --standard-pkgs /
```

**Output:**

```
Permissions differ on "tmp", should be drwxrwxrwt , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
```

**To repair disk permissions:**

```
sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /
```

**Output:**

```
Permissions differ on "tmp", should be drwxrwxrwt , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
Unable to set owner & group on "tmp". Error 1: Operation not permitted
Unable to set permissions on "tmp". Error 1: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: do not know if this is the case, but in my case it was not possible to install xcode 8 without upgrading to macOS Sierra. It is very likely that there are dependencies among them, I find no reason why you did not show the same warning to you

Comment: I  don't have macOS Sierra on my Mac Mini. How that can affect working on Xcode simulators?

Comment: What is the output of `stat /tmp` and `stat /private/tmp`?

Comment: @jose920405 There is no dependency on macOS Sierra.  The issue here (and likely in your case) is that we can't create a temporary directory in /tmp.  That is almost always due to user error (eg: deleting /tmp), but given the recent deluge of people hitting this issue, I suspect that a 3rd part installer or a bad blog post or something might be to blame.  I've seen about 10 reports of issues like this on stackoverflow over the past two weeks but not a single report which includes the necessary data to understand how the system got into that state in the first place.

Comment: Also, what is the output of `pkgutil --file-info /tmp` and `pkgutil --file-info /private/tmp`

Comment: Also, what is the output of `sudo ls -lO / /tmp /var /private /private/tmp /private/var`

Answer (score 7):

This error indicates that launchd_sim is unable to create its temporary state directory (/private/tmp/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice....launchd_sim).

This can happen if /private/tmp is deleted or has changed permissions.

There have been a high volume of reports of this issue lately.  The reason appears to be that the restricted bit is getting set on /private/tmp, which is why some users have reported that disabling SIP acts as a workaround for this issue.

The correct fix is to remove the restricted bit from that path.  If you boot your system into recovery mode and launch Terminal, you should be able to do this with:

```
chflags norestricted /Volumes/.../private/tmp
```

or a larger hammer:

```
rm -rf /Volumes/.../private/tmp
mkdir /Volumes/.../private/tmp
chmod 1777 /Volumes/.../private/tmp
chown root:wheel /Volumes/.../private/tmp
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have been facing the same issue with other applications such as Android Studio also. I have tried this command: "sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --verify --standard-pkgs /" to check if there are any permissions issues and I found that the permissions for the "/tmp" folder is changed.

Comment: Please provide the requested data in a radar and mention the ticket number here.  Thanks.

Comment: Posted the bug in radar. Token number is: 28976244

Comment: What if I boot my mac in recovery mode and try command: 'csrutil disable'  followed by command: sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /. Will I be able to fix the permissions change issue>?

Comment: Thanks for the radar.  I think we've figured out the cause, so no more data is needed.  I've been told that repair_packages doesn't work any more, but I see it still exists in ElCap, so maybe that comment was just referring to Sierra.  You can certainly give it a try, but it might not work.  We're working on rolling out a fix for the issue, so another option is to sit tight for a little bit if that doesn't work.

Comment: If you're willing to boot into recovery mode, a better option is to just fix the directory directly.

Comment: After install/resintall clearing folders... just one command fix it - `chmod 1777 /private/tmp`. I just don't know if is safe to set o+w to this folder.

Comment: @Vagner See chmod(2) and sticky(8) for information on the sticky bit for why that is safe.

Answer (score 6):

These commands did the trick for me:

```
sudo chown root:admin /tmp; sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
sudo chown root:wheel /private/tmp; sudo chmod 1777 /private/tmp
```

Comment: Fixed my Xcode 12.2 (12B45b) issue, should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo chmod 1777 /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/private/tmp
```

worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, for some reason, your system has orphaned launch_sim processes.

The solution is to:

1. quit the simulator
2. open Activity Montior and search for sim.
3. manually Force Quit any launch_sim, ScriptAgent, or instruments processes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am not finding any process with name "launch_sim" or "ScriptAgent".

Comment: did you quit the simulator before searching for sim?

Comment: Yes @Maniganda.

Comment: Do you find launchd_sim?

Comment: NO, don't have any process with the name "launchd_sim".