# launchd_sim quit unexpectedly, xcode 9.3 (9E145)

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

After newest update high sierra & xcode day before I have this error everytime when I'm going to the storyboard, old project or new doesn't matter, I'm trying everything in this post, thinking maybe this help me:
[Xcode quits unexpectedly every time I open my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600029/xcode-quits-unexpectedly-every-time-i-open-my-project) 
and still nothing, then I'm re-install XCode, and still the same problem, all day wasted by trying to fix this error different ways.. maybe someone know something?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdJ7S.png

Comment: Similar kind of issue is answered here at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238266/launchd-sim-crashing-could-not-create-temporary-state-directory?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying some things from that answers too, what I understand is that this error because some permission, how to enable this permission not clear yet and at the top message: "The issue is fixed with recent update of Mac OSX." But recent update MacOS crashed my XCode :(

Comment: If anyone will have the same error and looking for answer in stackoverflow know it - nothing is working. I just install clear High Sierra, download all again, then XCode and simulator is work well. 
I guess problem was in bad update XCode or High Sierra, don't know what exactly because my updates was at the same time.